# Excel formula for IF cell number is 'lower' than X, 'in between' X and Y or 'higher' Y then equals A, B, C

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I can get a simple IF formula working like: `=IF(A3>100,"good","bad")`

but what i would like is something that works for in between theses values too.

Example:

A score of `<80 = Bad`, `80-100 = OK`, `>100 = Good`
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You embed if statements:

```
=IF(A3>100,"good",IF(A3>80,"OK","bad"))
```

(not that if the maximum score is 100, then you should use:

```
=IF(A3>=100,"good",IF(A3>80,"OK","bad"))
```

Comment: Mine gets shorter if there are more than three options, but with 3 or less IF is shorter.

Comment: Should that second `IF` be `IF(A3>=80`?

Comment: I think your are right Chronocidal as i swapped the text around to what i thought it would be but then worked great, thanks.

Comment: I have hit several more issues if any of you could help i would really appreciate it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198878/excel-formulae-conditional-outcomes-based-on-other-formulae

Answer (score 3):

Use INDEX()

```
=INDEX({"Bad","OK","Good"},MATCH(A3,{-1E+99,80,100}))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `{0,80,100.01}` or something, since `80 ≤ "OK" ≤ 100` rather than `80 ≤ "OK" < 100`?

Comment: @Chronocidal probably, but I will leave that to the OP.

Comment: That one didn't quite work as there are negative scores too, not sure what to change.

Comment: Change the `0` to `-1E+99` to include all negative numbers.

Comment: Make the first number massively negative: `{-1E99,80,100.01}`

Comment: I have hit several more issues if any of you could help i would really appreciate it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198878/excel-formulae-conditional-outcomes-based-on-other-formulae